# Firefox wont load this page but other browsers will, why?

Tags: firefox

This is driving me crazy. This website and its pages work perfectly in IE, and Chrome but in Firefox 5.0 it frequently won't load the belts and bags page and the only way to get it to load is clear my cache/history.

http://www.urlgone.com/0ad9a6/

If you click around four times on the Bags link, then the belts link, then the Bags, then the accessories link it usually won't load. Another testing process is when you click Belts or Bags twice each then hit refresh it gets stuck and never loads or eventually after a long wait does. It seems to do this on either Belts or Bags but its
not always the same page that has problems.

Can anyone give me a clue what the problem is?

Comment: Functionality seems identical across all browsers on my system.

Comment: I figured the problem out. Its more specific to my individual situation i guess. 

I thought maybe my problem was the wordpress include header file but I was wrong.  It appears to be permalinks. I changed my permalinks to  default and it worked.  

Next I did a restart with Firefox in Safe Mode using pretty permalinks (not default) and it worked fine. So ultimately the problem in Firefox is an add-ons in combination with the permalink somehow. I found the culprit add-on is HTML Validator 0.9.0.6. I'm not sure why this is the problem but appears it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem out. Its more specific to my individual situation i guess. I thought maybe my problem was the word press include header file but I was wrong. It appears to be permalinks. I changed my perma links to default and it worked. Next I did a restart with Firefox in Safe Mode using pretty permalinks (not default) and it worked fine. So ultimately the problem in Firefox is an add-ons in combination with the permalink somehow. I found the culprit add-on is HTML Validator 0.9.0.6. I'm not sure why this is the problem but appears it is.